# on-click method on a button that directs to another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I have a main app page component with a search bar. The Search results that come back is in cards And I am looking to set up a  "Click here to view more detail" that would be placed in each card. And it would link to the Details page of the one result clicked. How do I link these components on Vue and if the id could be passed? I am hoping that upon click of the button the component renders on the same page and not a new tab.

Thank you!

App.vue

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header/>
    <SearchForm v-on:search="search"/>
    <SearchResults
      v-if="results.length > 0"
      v-bind:results="results"
      v-bind:reformattedSearchString="reformattedSearchString"/>

    <Pagination
      v-if="results.length > 0"
      v-bind:prevPageToken="api.prevPageToken"
      v-bind:next_page="api.scrollId"
      v-on:prev-page="prevPage"
      v-on:next-page="nextPage"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/layout/Header';
import SearchForm from './components/SearchForm';
import SearchResults from './components/SearchResults';
import Pagination from './components/Pagination';
import Details from './components/Details'
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Header,
    SearchForm,
    SearchResults,
    Pagination,
    Details
  },

   data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      reformattedSearchString: '',
      api: {
        baseUrl: 'https://test.org/api/v1/articles?',
        max: 25,
        q: '',
        prevPageToken: '',
        scrollId: ''
      }
    };
  },


   methods: {
    search(searchParams) {
      this.reformattedSearchString = searchParams.join(' ');
      this.api.q = searchParams.join('+');
      const { baseUrl, q, max} = this.api;
      const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}&term=${q}&title_like=${q}&recent&max=${max}&full_results`;
      this.getData(apiUrl);

    },

    prevPage() {
      const { baseUrl, q, max, prevPageToken } = this.api;
      const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}&term=${q}&title_like=${q}&max=${max}&pageToken=${prevPageToken}`;
      this.getData(apiUrl);
    },

    nextPage() {
      const { baseUrl, q, max,scrollId } = this.api;
      const apiUrl = `${baseUrl}&term=${q}&title_like=${q}&max=${max}&recent&full_results&scroll_id=${scrollId}`;
      this.getData(apiUrl);
    },

    getData(apiUrl) {
      axios
        .get(apiUrl)

        .then(res => {
          this.results = res.data.success.data;
          this.api.prevPageToken = res.data.success.data.prevPageToken;
          this.api.next_page = res.data.scrollId;

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Searchresults.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container mb-3">
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">
      <div class="mr-auto">
        <h3>Search Results for "{{ reformattedSearchString }}"</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group ml-auto" role="group">
        <button
          @click="changeDisplayMode('grid')"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          v-bind:class="{ active: displayMode === 'grid' }"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-th"></i>
        </button>
        <button
          @click="changeDisplayMode('list')"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
          v-bind:class="{ active: displayMode === 'list' }"
        >
          <i class="fas fa-list"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-columns" v-if="displayMode === 'grid'">
      <div class="card" v-bind:key="result._gddid" v-for="result in results">
        <ArticleGridItem v-bind:result="result"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div class="card mb-2" v-bind:key="result._gddid" v-for="result in results">
        <ArticleListItem v-bind:result="result"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ArticleListItem from './ArticleListItem';
import ArticleGridItem from './ArticleGridItem';
import Details from './Details';

export default {
  name: 'SearchResults',
  components: {
    ArticleListItem,
    ArticleGridItem,
    Details,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Search Results',
      displayMode: 'grid'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeDisplayMode(displayMode) {
      this.displayMode = displayMode;
    }
  },
  props: ['results', 'reformattedSearchString']
};
</script>
```

ArticleListItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card-body"> 
    <h6 class="card-text">{{ result.title }}</h6>

      <p
        class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"
      >{{ result.publisher }} | {{ result.journal }} | {{ result.year }}</p>
      <a :href="'https://test.org/api/articles?docid=' + result._gddid" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-download"  alt="Download"> </i>
      </a>
     <router-link>
    <v-btn dark to="{name:'Details', params: {id: article._gddid}}">
    Click here for more Details
    </v-btn>
  </router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ArticleListItem',
  props: ['result'],   
}

</script>
```

index.js

```
  import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Details from '@/components/Details';


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
     path: '/Details/:id',
     name: 'Details',
     component: Details
   }
 ]
});
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index.js'
import moment from 'moment'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return moment(value.toString()).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm')
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: you can build a common router for detail page.  If the list page called `/list`, then this common router is `/list/:id`, then you can leverage `<router-link />` or `this.$router.push()` to go to detail view, but remember, you should pass `id` param, like `this.$router.push("/list/thisIsItemId")`, then in the detail page, you get `id` from `this.$route.params.id`

Answer (score 1):

use `<router-link>` tag for it to work

Answer (score 0):

When using Vue Router, instead of using `<a>` tags, you can use `<router-link>` tags.

Here's a basic example similar to [the Vue Router documentation for dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html).

If you have this...

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/Details/:id', component: DetailsPage, name: 'Details' }
  ]
})
```

You can have router-links declared in, say, your `ArticleListItem.vue` file like:

```
<v-btn dark to="{name:'Details', params: {id: article.id}}">
  Click here for more Details
</v-btn>
```

You can't just go to a generic details page. There needs to be some dynamic part of the route (which I've called `id` in my example) to specify which article's page to go to.

**Edit**

An additional problem is in your Router setup:

[From the Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

...needs to be in your main.js file. The declaration of `Vue.use` in your index.js file isn't doing anything. Just for conciseness. Make it one file:

**WhateverYourOneTrueFileIsGoingToBeCalled.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Details from '@/components/Details';
import moment from 'moment'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.filter('formatDate', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  return moment(value.toString()).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm')
})

Vue.use(VueRouter)

router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
     path: '/Details/:id',
     name: 'Details',
     component: Details
   }
 ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: I added the const router to my index.js which the router page. where would I put the <router-link>?

Comment: <router-link> tags go in your templates and take the place of where you would otherwise use an <a> tag in your HTML

Comment: Okay so I updated my code. I added the router-link to the ArticleListItem.vue and I keep getting a error on my index.js saying 'router' is assigned a value but never used. I'm sure my index.js isn't correct.

Comment: Yes. You are importing router but it's not being exported. In your `router/index.js` you need `export default router` as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: okay I updated that but It still doesn't work it just updates the link to http://localhost:8081/#/{name:'/Details',%20params:{id:result._gddid} but doesn't change page

Comment: Apologies. I missed a closing brace in the router-link. The end of the tag should be `article.id}}"`

Comment: Anytime you get a URL with a `#` at the end, that's Vue Router's way of telling you your link is going to an undefined route. That means you need to check both your router-link and your Router definitions for typos.

Comment: okay! I checked and I couldn't find anything. So when I do router-link it makes my click for details button disappear. and I get this Property or method "results" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.. Just wondering if my details page is not set up correctly.

Comment: You've wrapped your v-btn in a <router-link> which is incorrect. The v-btn component looks like is already uses vue-router underneath, looking at it's documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/

Comment: yeah that doesn't seem to work. I'll just be using Router-link. But I can still not figure out the router problem or why I get http://localhost:8081/#/{name:'Details',%20params:%20{id:%20result.id}}

Comment: What happens when you just type the address in your browser? Not using a link? Does the details page show?

Comment: Ok, your VueRouter as a whole wasn't wired up correctly. The `Vue.use` was in the wrong file. See above edits

Comment: So the main.js and router file(index.js) can be merged together?

Comment: Yes they can! :)

Comment: I get error: 'router' is not defined  if I include that in my main.js

Comment: Have you defined router?

Comment: I just added the script to the main. I am guessing I didn't define the router.